# How can sphinx find words in cli search, but not in php script?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, sphinx

For some words, I get matches in both the command line search tool, and in a php script.

But for other words, I get say 1 result in the command line, and no results at all in the php script.

I have tried these:

indexer --all

indexer --rotate

Close the searchd window and execute it again

Restart the apache

Etc.

But I'm still getting 1 result in the command line, 0 results in the script.

Any ideas?

I'm on windows 7, xampp, and sphinx 0.9.9

No, I'm not gonna use that for production. Only for development / testing.

Edit: Changes to the index reflected on the script after a reboot. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The command line search script executes a basic search with no options against all indexes, if you're selecting an index within PHP, or setting any options you can limit the scope of results and end up omitting results.